# Jquery animate height on click removes the element

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-animate

I want to resize a div from 100% to 50% percent of height on div. but when I click the button the div animate but hides. and when I click again the div comebacks to 100% size.

what I want is that when I click on a button the div will resize to 50 %. then I click again it can resize to 100% this is the sample code.

```
$("#abc").click(function () {
    $(".main-footer").slideToggle("slow");
    $('#map').toggle(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "500px"
        }, 200);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "100%"
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: But you have made it 500px not 50%, am I missing something here?

Comment: function `toggle` hides the div completely.

Answer (score 0):

`Toggle` function hide/show the element. You have to check the div height and do the action based on it.

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div id="map" style="height:100px;background-color:red">Sample div</div>
 <input type="button" id="abc" value="ABC">
```

**JS**

```
$("#abc").click(function () 
{
     s = $('#map').css('height');
     if(s == '100px')
     {
        $('#map').animate({
           height: "50px"
        }, 200);
     }
     else
     {
         $('#map').animate({
             height: "100px"
         }, 200);
     }
});
```

Comment: the code works with pixels but when i set to percentage it wont work

Comment: the thing is i want this to be in percentage